# Visual Studio extension to perform refactoring adding new file as dependency

Tags: c#, roslyn

I started a new code refactoring project from the template that reverses Type names. After the renaming of some test type in a simple winforms application I want to add a file to the project so it shows under file Form1.cs like the  file Form1.Designer.cs does so it is grouped like a folder. My code adds the file but does not associate it like I want, it shows up at the same level as Form1.cs. Here is the part I added after the renaming code:

```
 // my code
        var docid = DocumentId.CreateNewId(document.Project.Id);
        var folders = new List<string>() { "Form1.cs" };
        var sln = newSolution.AddAdditionalDocument(docid, "comment.cs", 
            SourceText.From("//help find parent!!"),
            ImmutableArray.CreateRange(folders));


        return sln;
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's possible with Roslyn APIs only.

Comment: I found a solution from  Mads Kristensen nested files extension. Thanks!